# Is there any way to get settlement figures in the local currency from Amazon MWS?

Tags: amazon-mws, currency-exchange-rates

We're using 3 marketplaces - our local is UK, so we've got GBP figures for the payment settlement reports, but the other 2 are in EUR.  I could do with at least knowing how much Amazon have paid us in GBP for the 2 EUR reports, but I can't see any way of doing that?

I'm open to the idea of using some other API to get Amazon's payout exchange rates on the date of the report or other ideas.

I realise that I can use an external currency exchange data source, but I want to know what Amazon's exchange rate is for paying out since they almost certainly won't match.

I have tried all 3 settlement reports: -

_GET_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_

_GET_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_

_GET_ALT_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_

Answer (score 2):

All settlement information uses the currency of the corresponding marketplace: your Amazon.co.uk settlement will be in GBP, while an Amazon.de settlement will be in EUR. The conversion to another currency is not part of the settlement.

IIRC, it is the bank that actually converts it to GBP, not Amazon. Therefore, you will not find an Amazon API to find its conversion rate (or conversion fees for that matter).

Comment: Amazon do list the conversion rate in seller central though (and an estimated one before the deposit has taken place), so they do have the data and there is no reason they couldn't make that available through an API

Comment: @wizzardmr42 - if they do show it inn Seller Central, I certainly don't see it anywhere in the API. So your options are: a) crawl the Seller Central site or b) contact Amazon and ask for an API (or the extension of an existing call)